# Confusion about principles of decimal approximation

Tags: calculus, approximation

I ran into this paragraph in the introductory chapter on Taylor series of Morris Kline's "Calculus: An Intuitive And Physical Approach":

*"Thus, if the value of $\sin(x)$ for a particular value of $x$ is needed to five decimal places, the mathematician will make certain that the error is indeed no greater than the quantity $0.000,005$"*

I don't understand that. Let's say that the exact value of $sin(x)$ for a certain $x$, or any other function for that matter, is $0.836,229$. The exact value up to $5$ decimal places would then be $0.83,622$.

However, with an error of $+0.000,005$, the original value would be $0.836,234$ and therefore the value up to $5$ decimal places would end being $0.83,623$, which would be wrong.

Am I missing something or is there an error in the text?

Comment: In my view you got it right. In fact, it doesn't matter how small you make your error, there will be some $x$ for which an approximation within that error will not give you the correct five decimals (e.g, if your allowed error is $\epsilon<10^{-1}$, you can take $x$ with $sin(x)=0.9-\epsilon/4$ but your approximation might yield $0.9+\epsilon/4$, and already the first decimal will be wrong.)

Comment: Your statement that the exact value of 0.836229 to five decimal place precision is 0.83622 is factually incorrect. The exact value of 0.836229 to five decimal place precision is 0.83623.

Comment: Note that exactness is not a Platonic form, it is a measurable quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that $x=0.83623$ means that $0.836225\le x<0.836235$. Or, roughly speaking $\vert x-0.83623\vert<0.000005$.

This is five decimal place precision.

Comment: Thank you, your comment to my original post also helped. I was initially thinking that rounding up wouldn't give us an "exact" value, but I realize that once you truncate a decimal place from the actual exact value you're not getting an exact value anymore anyway, so in this case the rounded approximation is the closest thing to exact you can get.